# Creating Ubuntu 18.04 bootable USB...bootloader fails?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, bootloader

I've been trying to create this bootable USB for hours. I have the `.iso` and everytime I get right to the end, it fails to write the bootloader to the USB. I'm currently using 14.04 and just trying to get the USB set up to do a new install. I don't use the old laptop much anymore and have put off the update far too long.

So now 14.04 has been officially killed off. Stuck like chuck. What's the fix? Anybody?

Comment: use etcher to create one!

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   Maybe your ISO is invalid; thus any writes to install-media fail because of a bad ISO download?   I'd start with validating your ISO.  Myself I use `dd` (I'd not recommend in your case though!!) but https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto maybe helpful  (it's rather old, maybe https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 is better as works on 14.04 at least)

Answer (score 0):

When booting the Ubuntu installation ISO, please select the option "Check disc for defects".

If it passes consider installing from a different media, ie: USB instead of DVD.

If it fails then try to create a new installation media.